# Alignment of equations that contain Feynman diagrams

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, feynmf

I want to insert a Feynman diagram into an equation, but when I do so, I find that the Feynman diagram and the rest of the equation are awkwardly aligned.  The picture should make it pretty clear what I mean.  Is there a way to center the expression in this equation with the Feynman diagram?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{feynmf}

\begin{document}

\begin{fmffile}{test}
\begin{equation}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(65,50)
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmf{plain}{i1,v,o1}
\fmf{plain}{i2,v,o2}
\end{fmfgraph*}=-i\lambda
\end{equation}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `gathered`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto} % or feynmf

\begin{document}

\begin{fmffile}{test}
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(65,50)
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmf{plain}{i1,v,o1}
\fmf{plain}{i2,v,o2}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{gathered}=-i\lambda
\end{equation}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,feyn}
\usepackage{relsize}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\feyn{x}}}\quad=-i\lambda
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

...using `feyn` and `relsize` package.